# Cumsum until threshold

Tags: matlab, sum, cumsum

I wonder if there is a *fast* way to keep summing an element until a threshold is found.

For example

```
threshold=100;
a=0; MAX=1000;
for i=1:MAX
    a=a+normrnd(2,1,1,1);
    if (a>threshold)
      index=i; break;
     end 
 end
```

This works fine, but it is quite slow. Cumsum would be really useful here. However, the only way I know to use cumsum in this situation is like this:

```
a=cumsum(normrnd(2,1, MAX,1)); 
index=find(a>threshold,1);
```

Which become progressively more inefficient when MAX increase.

So basically I am looking for a cumulative summation method that preserve the speed of cumsum but that allows me to set a threshold.
Any idea? 
Thank you

Comment: Does the data come from a known distribution like `normrnd` or is that just for illustration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this solution combines both your solutions, it iterates over segments of size 1000 and uses your cumsum solution to process 1000 elements at once.

```
threshold=100;
a=0; MAX=9999999;
%segment size
S=1000;
for segment_start=1:S:MAX
    %process segment from _start to _end
    segment_end=min(segment_start+S-1,MAX);
    %which contains _count elements
    segment_count=segment_end-segment_start+1;
    %now use the cumsum solution to process the segment
    c=normrnd(2,1,segment_count,1);
    c=cumsum(c);
    index=find(c>threshold-a,1,'first');
    if isempty(index)
        %need to continue
        a=a+c(end);
    else
        %threshhold reached, found solution
        a=a+c(index);
        break;
    end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a binary search. If your elements are random variables with a known distribution, or at least known expected value you can make a good initial guess.

In the case you have posted, we have that `E[normrnd(2,1,1,1)] = 2`, and since `threshold = 100` you start by generating 50 numbers and summing them. If you overestimate then you search for the correct index with binary search. If you underestimate then you use the amount you underestimated to make a new guess, and continue to do so untill you overestimate.